# Why do I get strange results from the Kolmogorov–Smirnov two sample test?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, interpretation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm trying to understand the output of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov two sample test. I have two columns, test1 and test2. I'm having some difficulty in understanding the interpretation of the counterintuitive results I am getting.

```
structure(list(test1 = c(0.43, 0.16, 0.18, 0.13, 0.1, 0.23, 0.07, 
0.06, 0.13, 0.14, 2, 0.21, 0.29, 0.35, 0.33, 0.56, 0.26, 0.26, 
0.14, 0.19, 0.38, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0.74, 0.53, 1, 1, 0.32, 
0.17, 0.11, 0.09, 0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.004, 0.01, 0.95), test2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
0.74, 0.53, 1, 1, 0.32, 0.17, 0.11, 0.09, 0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 
0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.004, 0.01, 0.95, 
0.43, 0.16, 0.18, 0.13, 0.1, 0.23, 0.07, 0.06, 0.13, 0.14, 2, 
0.21, 0.29, 0.35, 0.33, 0.56, 0.26, 0.26, 0.14, 0.19, 0.38, 7, 
1)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I did run the two sample KS test as follows:

```
ks.test(data$test1, data$test2)
```

Why does the test result indicate that the two distributions are similar?

```
Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  Data$test1 and Data$test2
D = 0, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

If I plot test1 and test2, visual inspection obviously shows that the two distributions are not similar.

```
> plot(Data$test1, type="l",col="red")
> lines(Data$test2,col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: What does a histogram of each dataset look like? If I make a vector `x=rnorm(10)` then run `plot(x, type="l")` and `plot(x[10:1], type="l")` I will get two very different plots because of the type of plot. Their histograms will be identical. the ks test would return a value of 1 as well.

Comment: The histograms are identical indeed. Why is there such a difference between the line plots and histograms? I thought the KS test focuses on the distribution as laid down in the line plot.

Comment: A distribution is best visualised by a histogram (at least, for univariate data). A line plot is displaying the data by the order it was entered into R (which might perhaps correspond to the order it was observed). When we don't take "time" into account `x` and `x[10:1]` are identical

Comment: The K-s test compares ECDFs, not 'line plots'. Your plots show data in order of listing, which is different btw the two samples. They are not directly relevant to the K-S test. See ECDFs in my Answer.

Answer (score 3):

The distributions are not only *similar*, they are *identical*.

Your two columns contain the same values, only shifted circularly. The KS test is not any sort of paired test; it's comparing two *distributions* for which the order does not matter.

Comment: But that means it ignores the location (mean) of the distribution, correct? I am aiming to test the similarity of both the shape and location of the two distributions as shown in the line plots.

Comment: @Jonathan It doesn't look like you are plotting distributions, you are just plotting the *data*. The distribution of the sample (or an approximation of the underlying distribution) is from a histogram of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Outline for 'troubleshooting' test and data:

```
test1 = c(0.43, 0.16, 0.18, 0.13, 0.1, 0.23, 0.07, 
 0.06, 0.13, 0.14, 2, 0.21, 0.29, 0.35, 0.33, 0.56, 0.26, 0.26, 
 0.14, 0.19, 0.38, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0.74, 0.53, 1, 1, 0.32, 
 0.17, 0.11, 0.09, 0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 
 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.004, 0.01, 0.95)

test2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
 0.74, 0.53, 1, 1, 0.32, 0.17, 0.11, 0.09, 0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 
 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.004, 0.01, 0.95, 
 0.43, 0.16, 0.18, 0.13, 0.1, 0.23, 0.07, 0.06, 0.13, 0.14, 2, 
 0.21, 0.29, 0.35, 0.33, 0.56, 0.26, 0.26, 0.14, 0.19, 0.38, 7, 1)

ks.test(test1, test2)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  test1 and test2
D = 0, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(test1, test2) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

What is the source of the ties?

```
length(test1)
[1] 50
length(unique(test1))
[1] 32
length(test2)
[1] 50
length(unique(test2))
[1] 32
```

Each sample contains 18 duplicated observations.

Finally, the K-S test works by comparing empirical cumulative distribution
functions (ECDFs). Here are the two ECDFs: one with orange dots, the other
with blue `+`s. As @BryanKrause (+1) says, the two samples have identical
observations---even if they are listed in different orders.

```
plot(ecdf(test1), col="orange")
 lines(ecdf(test2), col="blue", pch="+")
```

[image]

In this instance, Warning notwithstanding, the K-S test has given exactly the correct
P-value, which is $1.$

Here are sorted listings of the data, which make it easy to spot ties--
both within and between samples:

```
sort(test1)
 [1] 0.004 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.020 0.030 0.030
[11] 0.040 0.040 0.060 0.070 0.090 0.100 0.100 0.110 0.130 0.130
[21] 0.140 0.140 0.160 0.170 0.180 0.190 0.210 0.230 0.260 0.260
[31] 0.290 0.320 0.330 0.350 0.380 0.430 0.530 0.560 0.740 0.950
[41] 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 2.000 2.000 7.000
sort(test2)
 [1] 0.004 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.020 0.030 0.030
[11] 0.040 0.040 0.060 0.070 0.090 0.100 0.100 0.110 0.130 0.130
[21] 0.140 0.140 0.160 0.170 0.180 0.190 0.210 0.230 0.260 0.260
[31] 0.290 0.320 0.330 0.350 0.380 0.430 0.530 0.560 0.740 0.950
[41] 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 2.000 2.000 7.000
```

Also, data summaries are identical, so there is no difference in sample means as you claim.

```
summary(test1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0040  0.0625  0.1850  0.5167  0.5525  7.0000 
summary(test2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0040  0.0625  0.1850  0.5167  0.5525  7.0000
```